# Fetchall() limitado em python

Tags: python, postgresql

Estou fazendo um código que faz uma consulta no postgres e retorna em uma lista, porém isso está dando erro de memória. A parte do código que faz isso:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT latitude, longitude, gid FROM pontos")  
records = c.fetchall() #pega todos os resultados do select e armazena em uma tupla
e = conn.cursor()
e.execute("SELECT precipitacaoh, gidgeo_fk FROM historico")
records2 = e.fetchall()
```

Como faço pra pegar, por exemplo, os 100 elementos da consulta e armazenar no disco, e depois pegar os próximos 100 elementos, até armazenar toda a consulta? Pra não sobrecarregar o sistema.

Comment: Pelo seu comentário abaixo, seu erro não tem nada a ver com a quantidade de dados - inclua a mensagem de erro que acontece efetivamente.S e o código já mudou, pode ser melhor fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade, nao apresenta erro, o sistema simplesmente trava. Já deixei o código rodando uma noite inteira, tive que reiniciar o computador e não tinha incluído nenhum registro no novo banco.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer isso sim - eu me pergunto se será útil simplesmente armazenar os valores em um arquivo texto: em geral recuperar os dados desejados no banco de dados e processa-los diretamente é melhor do que pear os mesmos dados de um arquivo texto, onde não temos ferramenta de indexação, formas de fazer busca, etc...

me causa muito estranhamento você estar tendo um "erro de memória" com registros tão simples como esses - mesmo milhões de registros não deveriam exaurir a memória de um sistema com RAM na casa dos gigabytes.

Agora, voltando especificamente ao que você pergunta - os conectores de banco de dados do Python  - todos - implementam além do `fetchall`, o `fetchmany` - que retorna somente o número solicitado de registros.

Então, um jeito de transferir uma query para um arquivo local (que não considero que seja algo útil - a não ser que seja tudo o que você quer fazer com os dados) seria:

```
import csv
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT latitude, longitude, gid FROM pontos")

with open("arquivo_destino.csv", "wt") as file_:
    writer  = csv.writer(file_)
    writer.writerow(("latitude", "longitude"))
    records = True
    while records:
        records = c.fetchmany(100)
        writer.writerows(records)
...
```

O próprio cursor da conexão também pode ser usado como um iterador, 
retornando um resultado da query por vez se for usado numa query - essa forma de usar é melhor se você for consumir seus dados, em vez de simplesmente grava-los num arquivo local:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT latitude, longitude, gid FROM pontos")
for record in c:
      # do things with row result
```

(mas eu já vi implementações bugadas de coenxões ao banco em que interar o cursor dessa forma ficava muito lento - se for o caso, melhor fazer uma combinação com o fetchmany também).

Comment: Fiz a seguinte modificação no meu codigo, mas continua travando. Estou tentando migrar um banco de dados relacional para um banco de dados em grafo.

http://pastebin.com/rG3kMxuv

Comment: No código que você linkou você cria os arquivos num comando "with"  - e cria os escritores (writers) CSV - só que a idéia do comando "with" é justamente _Garantir_ que o arquivo seja fechado assim que você sai dele. Então os seus writes ficam com uma referência a arquivos fechados - não vai funcionar mesmo.

O With é algo que funciona melhor em trechos críticos de programa em que vários arquivos vão ser abertos (centenas ou milhares de vezes) para evitar vazemtno de recursos do sistema operacional caso alguns não sejam fechados. 

Nesse caso, abra os arquivos com "open"  mesmo, sem o "with".

Comment: mas ainda não entendi por que você não pode fazer o insert na nova base de dados imediatamente após ler do SQL - por que precisa do CSV intermediário?

Comment: Na verdade, o que eu queria era pegar os registros do banco de dados, por exemplo de 100 em 100 registros, e inserir no novo banco, e continuar até que todos os dados fossem inseridos. Porque se eu fizer o que faço no código original: records = c.fetchall(), isso trava totalmente o sistema. Então já queria pegar de 100 em 100 e já ir inserindo. Entendeu?